# Paginacion en un chart c#

Tags: c#, mvc, aplicación-web

ando en busca de alguna vista para poder mostrar varios datos en un chart, pero que tenga paginacion, ya que en mi actual chart los datos sobrepoblan el chart, ojala pudieran ayudarme, gracais

Comment: favor de leer [ask] la idea de la comunidad es apoyarnos, pero resolviendo dudas claras de programación; de eso que preguntas que has intentado o investigado?

Comment: Ok, lo siento!, lo tendre en cuenta